# Redhat/CentOS - `GLIBC_2.18' not found

Tags: linux, redis, centos, redhat, glibc

I was trying to run redis server (on a CentOS server) with specific module:

```
redis-server --loadmodule ./redisql_v0.9.1_x86_64.so
```

and getting error:

```
Module ./redisql_v0.9.1_x86_64.so failed to load: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ./redisql_v0.9.1_x86_64.so)
```

this is the linux version:

```
uname
Linux

cat /etc/*release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

Also this is what is showing for `/lib64/libc.so.6`:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.17, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36).
Compiled on a Linux 3.10.0 system on 2019-01-29.
Available extensions:
    The C stubs add-on version 2.1.2.
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
    RT using linux kernel aio
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>.
```

Also:

```
rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64
glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64
```

Tried as well:

```
yum install glibc* -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos-va.psychz.net
 * extras: repos-va.psychz.net
 * updates: repos-va.psychz.net
Package glibc-devel-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-utils-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-headers-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-static-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

What is the process of installing/setting GLIBC_2.18 on Centos/Redhat servers?

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can upgrade to the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8, which comes with glibc 2.28 and thus provides the `GLIBC_2.18` symbol version (and much more).

If you do not want to upgrade, you need a Redis build for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.  Red Hat provides a Software Collection with Redis 3.2 (available in the scl channels).  There is also a [CentOS build of Redis 3.2](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-redis32/), again as a software collection.  If that version is too old, you will have to build Redis from source.  [EPEL only contains Redis 3.2](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1155988) as well.

Upgrading glibc within a current release in Red Hat Enterprise Linux (or CentOS) is [not possible](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/17/upgrading-the-gnu-c-library-within-red-hat-enterprise-linux/).

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of `make` fails to remove its temporarily created files is due to fact that Windows and its WSL uses case-insensitive FS.

Use fsutil on windows and attr(getfattr/setfattr) on linux to change case sensitivity.